# Update Dynamo db table using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb table, with columns as id (partition key) and date.  I am trying to update the date where id=2, but I am getting below error as response:

```
message: "The provided key element does not match the schema"
__type: "com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException"
```

Below is my code:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId: 'MY_ACCESS_KEY',
    secretAccessKey: 'MY_SECRET_KEY'
});
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

export const updateData = (tableName : any, id : any, date : any) => {
        let params = {
            TableName: tableName,
            Key:{
                "id": id
            },
            UpdateExpression: `set date = :date`,
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {":date": date},
        };
        docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(data);
            }else{
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
    }
```

I am calling function like this:

```
updateData("mytable","2","2023-01-10")
```

I anyone confirm what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the type of the `id` key the DynamoDB table?  String or Number?

Comment: Type of id is string

Comment: Does your table have a sort key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` is a [reserved keyword in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html)

You need to use `ExpressionAttributeNames` param:

```
        let params = {
            TableName: tableName,
            Key:{
                "id": id
            },
            UpdateExpression: `set #date = :date`,
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {":date": date},
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#date":"date"}
        };
```

As for the exception, ensure that your tables partition key is `id` and if type String, and that the table does not have a sort key, otherwise you need to add the sort key also.

Comment: Thanks Lee, I was facing issue because of the sort key. Now it's resolved.